# Django Administration page displays strangely

Tags: django

[image: MY Django Administration Page]

My django administration page shows different appearance like this in Chrome Browser, but it shows correct appearance in FireFox.

Comment: Any errors in the developer console?

Comment: `Not Found: /facicon.ico` the only one output that looks like an error in console